# How to use NLTK countvectorizer in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk, text-mining, countvectorizer

I have used `csv` reader to read my `tsv` file, which contains three columns lie, sentiment and review.  I have created dicitonary to read my `tsv` file data as shown in code below. Next. I would like to use `NLTK` count `vectorizer` to count word frequency in my "review" column only. I am not sure how to approach using `CountVectorizer` module in `NLTK` along with dictionary.I am expecting the word frequency of each word in the review column in pandas dataframe.

**In below code:** Infile= Filename.tsv

Any help is appreciated!

*Note: I am new to python, please provide explanation with code.*

**Few data after running "print(state)" code**

```
{'lie': 'lie', 'sentiment': 'sentiment', 'review': 'review'}
{'lie': 'f', 'sentiment': 'n', 'review': "'Mike\\'s Pizza High Point, NY Service was very slow and the quality was low. You would think they would know at least how to make good pizza, not. Stick to pre-made dishes like stuffed pasta or a salad. You should consider dining else where.'"}
{'lie': 'f', 'sentiment': 'n', 'review': "'i really like this buffet restaurant in Marshall street. they have a lot of selection of american, japanese, and chinese dishes. we also got a free drink and free refill. there are also different kinds of dessert. the staff is very friendly. it is also quite cheap compared with the other restaurant in syracuse area. i will definitely coming back here.'"}
```

**Code so far**

```
mylist=[]
#tsv file reader
with open(infile,'rU') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile,dialect='excel',delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        if line[0].startswith('Data'):
            continue
        else:
            sentiment={}
            sentiment['lie']=line[0]
            sentiment['sentiment']=line[1]
            sentiment['review']=line[2]
            mylist.append(sentiment)
csvfile.close()

for state in mylist:
    print(state)
    vect = CountVectorizer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` clause could be simplified to:

```
            mylist.append(dict(lie=line[0],
                               sentiment=line[1],
                               review=line[2]))
```

except that you probably want to first cleanup the review text.
Write a function and store `preprocess(line[2])`
rather than storing the raw text.
Things you might want to do include [`.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) downcasing,
and ignoring punctuation, digits, and English stopwords.

Referring to a [datacamp tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/text-analytics-beginners-nltk), 
a vectorizer call will look something like this:

```
    cv = CountVectorizer(lowercase=True,
                         stop_words='english',
                         ngram_range=(1, 1),
                         tokenizer=token.tokenize)
```